# comparing datetime is 1 hour ahead

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to count the rows with a datetime less that 10 minutes ago but the current time its being compared to seems to be 1 hour ahead so Imm getting 0 results, if I go into my table and put some fields forward an hour then I get results.

Getting results:

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT check_log FROM members WHERE check_log >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)');
$row_count = $stmt->rowCount();
echo $row_count.' Members online.';
```

The datetime of the field of of typing this is 2013-07-11 16:54:12 and I'm getting no results but if I manually change the date time to 2013-07-11 17:54:12 I get 1 result the datetime was input seconds ago using:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

The 17:54:12 is my local time and 16:54:12 seem to be my servers time, is my compare trying to look into the future or is it using my local time as a reference?

Comment: You php and mysql time are different. Are you setting timezone in php?

Comment: What is the datatype of your `check_log` column?

Comment: Use a timestamp (an int representing seconds since epoch), which will always be the same no matter what timezone you are in. Compare this to the UTC/GMT timestamp. Convert it to a local timezone if you want to display it as a local time at some point, but in all other cases just work with the UTC/GMT time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP and MySQL don't agree on the current timezone.

Pass the desired time in as a literal from PHP to SQL instead of using `NOW()`.

Comment: I would not recommend this approach unless it's the only place he is querying datetime/timestamp column. Logic could go nuts if he forgets to rewrite all queries to using PHP date() and if he corrects timezone settings on both mysql & php he is much more safe (just my opinion).

Comment: @fliespl the solution is to use the *same* datetime source for all activity. Either MySQL or PHP. In this case, he's using MySQL and unhappy with the results. If he uses PHP, then I imagine he'll be able to figure out where he's going wrong.

Comment: @fliespl But yes, you should also have your timezone set correctly and consistently.

Comment: thanks ive switch my datetime input over to sql and it works now

Answer (score 0):

Always store date times in php's timezone.

One function you can particularly make use of is [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime).

```
$now = strtotime("now"); // current timestamp
$hour_later = strtotime("+1 hour"); // hour later
$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $now);
$hour_later = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $hour_later);
```